# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypdf2

Tags: python, ssl, installation

I'm trying to install pdf2 but the following error occurs
What could it be due to?

```
pip install PyPDF2

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pypdf2/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pypdf2/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))) - skipping
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyPDF2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyPDF2
```

Comment: Your computer is having a issue getting the SSL Certificate of PyPI. Try restarting your computer or changing Wifi to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it with another wifi